# Incorporate DST into SQL script

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime, dst

My original question was too compact and all over the place so I tried to clean it up here. Trying to figure out how to properly implement DST into my SQL script for USA.

a.ActualEnd = DateTime value  &   c.TimeZoneBias = minutes to offset based  on users local time

UPDATE: Entire Script Below

```
INSERT INTO [AS400].S062f7ar.APLUS83MDS.PEPAPPTS01  
(PPCONO, PPREP1, PPDATE, PPCOUNT)
select '1' as PPCONO, 
       b.new_SalesrepId as PPREP1, 
       MAX(CONVERT(varchar(8), 
       (a.ActualEnd - c.TimeZoneBias / cast(24 * 60 as float)), 112)) as PPDATE,       
       count(b.new_SalesrepId) as PPCOUNT 
from ActivityPointerBase as a
  join SystemUserExtensionBase as b 
   on b.SystemUserId = a.OwnerId
  join UserSettingsBase as c 
   on c.SystemUserId = b.SystemUserId
where b.new_SalesrepId <> '99999999' 
 and a.ActivityTypeCode = '4201' 
 and b.new_SalesrepId is not NULL 
 and a.StateCode = '1' 

 and CONVERT(varchar(8), 
             a.ActualEnd - c.TimeZoneBias / cast(24 * 60 as float), 
             112) >= dateadd(day,datediff(day,
                                            1,
                                          CONVERT(varchar(8), 
                                                  GetDate(), 
                                                  112)
                                         ),
                             0) 
 and CONVERT(varchar(8), 
             a.ActualEnd - c.TimeZoneBias / cast(24 * 60 as float), 
             112) < dateadd(day,datediff(day,
                                           0,
                                         CONVERT(varchar(8), 
                                                 GetDate(), 
                                                 112)
                                         ),
                             0)
 group by b.new_SalesrepId, 
   CONVERT(varchar(8), 
   (a.ActualEnd - c.TimeZoneBias / cast(24 * 60 as float)), 112)
 order by b.new_SalesrepId ASC;
```

Looking to properly incorporate DST for USA into this where statement. I don't want to have to manually change the script every time DST rolls around.

Comment: When dealing with multiple time zones and daylight savings time, it's much easier to simply store the datetimes in UTC within the database. Then your database comparisons don't require all the extra conversions you're attempting. Then the only two hurdles would be to ensure datetimes are being passed to the database are in UTC, and datetimes being pulled out are converted to the user's current local time upon display.

Comment: They are stored in UTC. I am trying to pull the data out and I'm successfully converting it to the users local time but I'm trying to see if it's an easy thing or if it's not worth it to mess with DST.

Comment: Then I'm confused what your example code is attempting to show. If all the datetimes are all stored in UTC within the database, why do you need to do any conversions at all in the WHERE-clause? Just compare one UTC datetime to another UTC datetime.

Comment: I'm extracting records and inserting them into an AS400 table for reporting in my script for all matching records from yesterday which is the where statement above. This job runs at 1:05am everynight. If a user in EST enters a matching record at 12:15am local time it gets stored in the database as 04:15:00 UTC, my statement will convert it to local army time so it would end up being 23:15 of the previous day because DST in not taken into effect, if it was, the record time stamp would be 00:15:00 and it would be perfect. Your thoughts?

Comment: Should I just let it be as is, no data is missed because I run it at 1:05am EDT now or is there a good solution to incorporate DST?

Comment: If a user enters a record at 12:15am EST, then it should be recorded as 05:15 UTC in the database. EST is UTC-05:00. If the user is in EDT, then it would be 04:15 UTC in the database. If the user is providing the timestamp, then they or the application should be providing the correct UTC timestamp to the database. If you're using a database function to automatically determine the current time, then SYSUTCDATETIME() or GETUTCDATE() should always provide the correct UTC timestamp regardless of DST.

Comment: User does provide timestamp and application converts to UTC for the database. I guess it's a little more complicated than what I'm providing. These are activity records in a crm that are stored as UTC and when I try to pull the records out of this actvity table I convert the time stamp of the activity based on their "c.timezonebias" in minutes as you can see above. DST can cause a record entered in between 12am and 1am of the next day to be included with the previous day. Thanks for your help on this!

Comment: Glad I've helped. If you're still looking for an answer, then you'll need to include a few more details in your question.

Comment: I've included the entire script. Maybe this will better help convey the situation. There is no frontend CRM application involved here to translate the TimeZoneBias and DST. TimeZoneBias and DST settings are stored in the database per user in 2 tables. Strictly taking records from CRM database and dumping them in an AS400 table.

Comment: Make sure you also recognize that the USA [changed DST rules in 2007](http://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/us-daylight-saving-extended.html).  If you have dates before then, you'll need a secondary set of rules.  Also, this is usually much easier in application code than in SQL Server.

Comment: Also, if you have users in Hawaii or Arizona, recognize that they don't follow DST there.

Comment: Thanks for the added info @Matt Johnson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Assumptions

Since these points are not explicitly defined in the question, I am stating my assumptions of them here.

1. The current server stores all dates and times in the database are UTC.
2. The query is to return all dates and times in user local time.
3. The query is to return all records within a date range, but according to each user's local time.
4. TimeZoneBias is an Americanized bias in minutes where a value of 420 is UTC-(420/60), or UTC-7 (MST), and value of -120 is UTC-(-120/60), or UTC+2 (EET).

### Solutions

I see three possible solutions.  I believe all of them could be feasible, assuming a bit of data migration is performed first on a couple of them.

### Solution 1 : DATETIMEOFFSET

Implement ActualEnd column as DATETIMEOFFSET type in table ActivityPointerBase.  The application will be required to provide timestamps with the user's current local offset.  Then simply use CONVERT(DATE, a.ActualEnd) to get the user's local date later on.  Even allows you to compare timestamps between users because the database can implicitly do the offset calculations when comparing two DATETIMEOFFSET values.  And there are functions to convert DATETIMEOFFSET to a UTC DATETIME for comparing against other tables.

```
SELECT '1' as PPCONO,
       b.new_SalesrepId AS PPREP1,
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), a.ActualEnd, 112) AS PPDATE,
       COUNT(b.new_SalesrepId) AS PPCOUNT
FROM ActivityPointerBase AS a
JOIN SystemUserExtensionBase AS b ON b.SystemUserId = a.OwnerId
WHERE b.new_SalesrepId <> '99999999' 
AND a.ActivityTypeCode = '4201' 
AND b.new_SalesrepId IS NOT NULL 
AND a.StateCode = '1' 
AND CONVERT(DATE, a.ActualEnd) = CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()))
GROUP BY b.new_SalesrepId,
         CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), a.ActualEnd, 112)
ORDER BY b.new_SalesrepId ASC;
```

### Solution 2: Store data you need

Store both the user local time and UTC time in the database. Since you obviously require user local time later on, make storing it a requirement of your system. Then you have both an ActualEnd and UserActualEnd column in the ActivityPointerBase table.

```
SELECT '1' as PPCONO,
       b.new_SalesrepId AS PPREP1,
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), a.UserActualEnd, 112) AS PPDATE,
       COUNT(b.new_SalesrepId) AS PPCOUNT
FROM ActivityPointerBase AS a
JOIN SystemUserExtensionBase AS b ON b.SystemUserId = a.OwnerId
WHERE b.new_SalesrepId <> '99999999' 
AND a.ActivityTypeCode = '4201' 
AND b.new_SalesrepId IS NOT NULL 
AND a.StateCode = '1' 
AND CONVERT(DATE, a.UserActualEnd) = CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()))
GROUP BY b.new_SalesrepId,
         CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), a.UserActualEnd, 112)
ORDER BY b.new_SalesrepId ASC;
```

### Solution 3: Reconstruct user local time

Build a system where you can reconstruct user local time from UTC timestamps.  I'll outline a simple one below, but it is by no means tested nor the only way to reconstruct them.

First, you're going to need a ObserveDst column in the UserSettingsBase table, because some states follow DST and some do not, therefore a TimeZoneBias is not enough data to reconstruct user local time.

```
  ObserveDst INT NOT NULL
```

Which will contain a value of 1 if they observe DST and 0 otherwise.

Second, you're going to need a table of the DST start and end timestamps, since they have changed the definitions over time, and could possibly do so again in the future.  I suggest a table that is broken up into intervals.  This way you can perform simple joins with other tables instead of defining and calling a function that operates per record.

```
CREATE TABLE Dst
(
  BeginDT DATETIME NOT NULL,
  EndDT DATETIME NOT NULL,
  DstBias INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(BeginDT)
);
```

And put an index of (BeginDT, EndDT, DstBias) on the table.  It's okay it includes all columns in this case because it's not going to be a very big table. For 2014, you'd have the following records:

```
('2014-01-01 00:00:00', '2014-03-09 02:00:00', 0)
('2014-03-09 02:00:00', '2014-11-02 03:00:00', 60)
('2014-11-02 03:00:00', '2015-01-01 00:00:00', 0)
```

The November hour may look a bit odd, but the purpose of this table is to move from local non-DST time to local DST time.  And 2014-11-02 03:00:00 EST is 2014-11-02 02:00:00 EDT.  Also, be aware that these are closed-open intervals, which means including the first timestamp and up to but not including the last timestamp.  If you have historic dates going back before DST, you can compress them all into a single interval.  You could even join the beginning and end intervals of each year, giving you only N+3 records for N years.

The United States Department of Transportation defines the federally mandated dates, for states that choose to observe Daylight Savings Time (http://www.dot.gov/regulations/daylight-saving-time). I suggest you look to them, or another reasonably official site for the correct dates for the years you need.

Then you just join the Dst table and perform basic offset calculations.

```
SELECT '1' as PPCONO,
       b.new_SalesrepId AS PPREP1,
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(MINUTE, d.DstBias*c.ObserveDst-c.TimeZoneBias, a.ActualEnd)), 112) AS PPDATE,
       COUNT(b.new_SalesrepId) AS PPCOUNT
FROM ActivityPointerBase AS a
JOIN SystemUserExtensionBase AS b ON b.SystemUserId = a.OwnerId
JOIN UserSettingsBase AS c ON c.SystemUserId = b.SystemUserId
JOIN Dst AS d ON DATEADD(MINUTE, -c.TimeZoneBias, a.ActualEnd) >= d.BeginDT AND DATEADD(MINUTE, -c.TimeZoneBias, a.ActualEnd) < d.EndDT
WHERE b.new_SalesrepId <> '99999999' 
AND a.ActivityTypeCode = '4201' 
AND b.new_SalesrepId IS NOT NULL 
AND a.StateCode = '1' 
AND CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(MINUTE, d.DstBias*c.ObserveDst-c.TimeZoneBias, a.ActualEnd)) = CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()))
GROUP BY b.new_SalesrepId,
         CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(MINUTE, d.DstBias*c.ObserveDst-c.TimeZoneBias, a.ActualEnd)), 112)
ORDER BY b.new_SalesrepId ASC;
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response @Sybeus, very thorough!